# 301 domain list redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to conditionally redirect a list of domains.

These are all pointed to the same IP so I need to ensure that the rules only takes effect if the domain is matched, before hitting a fallback at the end.

Something like this:

> If domain in 'a.com,b.com', 301 to new-domain-1.com
>
> Else if domain in 'c.com,d.com', 301 to new-domain-2.com
>
> Else if domain not equal to 'new-master-domain.com', 301 to new-master-domain.com

However I don't know how to go about writing such a redirect rule (which would go in the .htaccess file).

Comment: This is all explained in detail in the excellent documentation of apaches rewriting module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html Also you will find good examples in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup rewrite rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(a|b)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new-domain-1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(c|d)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new-domain-2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^new-master-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new-master-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```